# Multiple stateful components with Ember Router

Tags: ember.js

I am writing an Ember app that consists of a handful of complex, stateful components. I am having trouble wrapping my head around how Ember handles this kind of app as it is not the traditional CRUD app.

It is a highly interactive single page application. Some example components are
Xmpp Text Chat, 
Multi party audio,
Xmpp Shared whiteboard, and 
Pop up notifications

There is a global state (which I can see handling via the router) that sets the user context (who I am working with on the audio/whiteboard). What I don't quite understand is what role if any the router would play in setting chat context which is unrelated to Audio and Whiteboard but still stateful. I can't picture how the URL string from the router can reflect state from all of these components simultaneously.

Is this a case where I skip using the router entirely? If so how can I link my application's views/controllers? Up till now I have been using the router's connectOutlets method to link my views and controllers. Without calling this method what would be another (structured and organized) way to do this binding?

Thanks

Comment: FYI there is a new [router API](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/) that was recently added to Ember and it has been updated in the Ember guides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question!

- **Global state**: Use the router
- **Application state**: In controller singletons associated with your application components

As a general rule I recommend using the router to manage state that a user can bookmark or use browser forward/back buttons to interact with. Just guessing but for your app that might include id of the whiteboard.

Components like chat, audio, and notifications would typically exist and maintain state independent of the router. In some cases these components might behave differently depending on the route (like chat might bind to a specific channel depending on which whiteboard is shown) but the state of the chat widget itself be stored as properties on the ChatController singleton.

The ember guides are not complete yet, but you may find the last section of the controllers guide "Storing Application Properties" helpful http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/