# Using additional state machines with Ember.js Routes v2

Tags: ember.js

We're using v2 of Routing in Ember.js, and we have a situation where we display multiple associated models within a view. The application is an address book, and when we display a contact, we also display the first address of that contact and the first event you share with that contact. On this same view, we want to be able to add/edit/delete addresses and events. Because of the multiple associated models, it would be difficult and undesirable to keep the state in the URL using routes.

**Is it possible to define a new state machine for each of the associated models that would control the controllers & views?** I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147518/multiple-stateful-components-with-ember-router) which suggests to use singleton controllers with data objects to control the state, and I've seen some example blog posts that use v1 of Routes with additional state machines. I have not been able to find anyone using multiple state machines with v2 of Routes.

Thanks!